# Insatalling Windows 10 on a Mac SSD formatted as APFS

Tags: apfs

I'm trying to install Windows10 on my Macbook Air 2012. Boot Camp successfully finishes. When my computer reboots and I try to install using the USB iso, I get an error. Is it because my SSD is formatted as APFS? Is there a work around?

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: When Boot Camp successfully finishes do you mean that it boots into a disk partitioning window that allows you to create the space on your Mac's HD to install Windows? Because that is what creates the NTFS formatted partition by shrinking the APFS container.